# nextflow: tumor normal sample - how to make code organic

Tags: nextflow

I'm developing pipeline in nextflow it uses tools: fastp, bwa mem index, bwamem, gatk mark duplicates, gatk setupnmd, gatk applybqsr, gatk recalibrate. I do this using FASTQ.gz of normal and tumor DNA samples.
I'm interested to use mutect2, lancet and strelka in nextsteps. However, I am unable to write code in the pipeline that makes sense. I use loads of shell scripting in mutect2 to use tumor-normal.
To expand, I've input in FASTQ as tiny_n, tiny_t, where _n is normal and _t is tumor. I run pipeline until applybqsr for each individually. However, as I reach mutect2, I check if sample contains **_n** or otherwise, I then create an empty file for the output as required in the mutect2 process.

How do I overcome creating dummy/empty file?

Please see below code of **main.nf**:

```
params.raw_files="/sc/arion/projects/tiny/all_tumors_normals/tiny_*{R1,R2}.fastq"

include { FASTP} from './fastp_process.nf'
//include {bwa_index} from './index_process.nf'
include { align_bwa_mem} from './bwamem_process_already_index.nf'
include { gatk_markduplicates} from './gatk_markduplicates_process.nf'
include { recalibrate_bam } from './recalibratebam_process.nf'
include {setupnmdtags} from './setupnmdtags_process.nf'
include { applybqsr } from './applybqsr_process.nf'
include { mutect2 } from './mutect2_process.nf'
workflow {

        read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.raw_files) 

        FASTP(read_pairs_ch) 

        align_bwa_mem(FASTP.out.reads) 
        gatk_markduplicates(align_bwa_mem.out.sorted_bams)
        setupnmdtags(gatk_markduplicates.out.sorted_bam_mark_duplicates)
        recalibrate_bam(setupnmdtags.out.setupnmdtags_bam)

applybqsr(gatk_markduplicates.out.sorted_bam_mark_duplicates,recalibrate_bam.out.recalib_table)


mutect2(applybqsr.out.recal_bam)
}
```

below is code of mutect2 to handle only one sample, run for normal, create dummy/empty file for tumor sample, **mutect2_process.nf**:

```
process mutect2 {
        maxForks 3
        debug true
        tag "${sample_id}"
 memory '15 GB'

        input:
        tuple val(sample_id),path(bqsrbam)
        
        output:
        tuple val(sample_id),path("${sample_id}.mutect2out.vcf")
        

        script:
                         def avail_mem = task.memory ? task.memory.toGiga() : 0
                def java_options = [
        avail_mem ? "-Xmx${avail_mem}G" : "",
        "-XX:+UseSerialGC",
    ]

        """
        echo "${sample_id}\n"

        grep_value=\\\$(echo "${sample_id}|  | grep "_n" ")

        if [[ ! -z "\\\${grep_value}" ]]
        then 

                identifier=\\\$(echo ${sample_id} | awk -F"_" '{print \\\$1}')
                echo "\\\${identifier}"_t.sorted.markdup.recal.bam""

                ml gatk/4.1.3.0
gatk --java-options "${java_options.join(' ')}" Mutect2 -L $params.target -I "${params.outdir}/applybqsr/""\\\${identifier}"_t.sorted.markdup.recal.bam"" -I  "${params.outdir}/applybqsr/""\\\${identifier}"_n.sorted.markdup.recal.bam"" -normal \\\${identifier}"_n" -tumor \\\${identifier}"_t" --output ${sample_id}".mutect2out.vcf" -R $params.hg38genome

        else 
                echo "Nothing to do\n"
                touch ${sample_id}".mutect2out.vcf"
 
        fi

        """
        }


workflow.onComplete { 
        log.info ( workflow.success ? "Done mutect2!" : "Oops .. something went wrong in mutect2" )
}
```

There is a load of unix/shell code that does trivial checks. It runs gatk mutect2 oly when _n is found.
How do I overcome: output defined `tuple val(sample_id),path("${sample_id}.mutect2out.vcf")` ?
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a design problem here. A better way would be perform this operation in your *workflow* block. This would allow you to feed in the tumor and normal BAMs (and avoid accessing files outside of the working directory as previously discussed). You can use the [`map`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator to extract the patient or case id from the sample names and the [`filter`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#filter) operator to separate the samples into two channels. You could also use the [`branch`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#branch) operator for this like in the example below. The [`join`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) operator can then be used to join together the items emitted in a consistent way. For example:

```
workflow {

    ref_fasta = file( params.ref_fasta )
    targets = file( params.targets )

    ...

    applybqsr.out.recal_bam
        .branch { sample_id, bam ->

            def case_id = sample_id.substring(0, sample_id.lastIndexOf('_'))

            tumor: sample_id.toUpperCase().endsWith('_T')
                return tuple( case_id, sample_id, bam )

            normal: sample_id.toUpperCase().endsWith('_N')
                return tuple( case_id, sample_id, bam )

        }
        .set { cases_ch }

    joined_ch = cases_ch.tumor.join( cases_ch.normal )

    mutect2( joined_ch, ref_fasta, targets )
}
```

```
process mutect2 {

    tag { sample_id }

    module 'gatk/4.1.3.0'

    input:
    tuple val(case_id), val(tumor), path(tumor_bam), val(normal), path(normal_bam)
    path reference_fasta
    path intervals_bed

    output:
    tuple val(case_id), path("${case_id}.mutect2.vcf")

    script:
    def avail_mem = task.memory ? task.memory.toGiga() : 0
    def java_options = [
        avail_mem ? "-Xmx${avail_mem}G" : "",
        "-XX:+UseSerialGC",
    ]

    """
    gatk \\
        --java-options "${java_options.join(' ')}" \\
    Mutect2 \\
        -R "${reference_fasta}" \\
        -L "${intervals_bed}" \\
        -I "${tumor_bam}" \\
        -I "${normal_bam}" \\
        -normal "${normal}" \\
        -tumor "${tumor}" \\
        -O "${case_id}".mutect2.vcf"
    """
}
```

There's also likely an issue with how *applybqsr* is invoked. If you require [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels), most of the time what you'll want is one [queue channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) and one or more [value channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel). I suspect the inputs for *applybqsr* also need to be joined into a single queue channel.

Comment: I really don't understand what you did with `.branch` in applybqsr. Nextflow is so mysterious. How are you defining `normal:` and `tumor:` without define keyword? Also, I have samples as: MM_tiny_n_R1.fastq.gz MM_tiny_t_R1.fastq.gz Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Also, where is `cases.tumor` stored/created?

Comment: @DeathMetal Sorry that should have been `cases_ch.tumor`. Fixed now. The boolean expressions we define in our branch closure can be given unique labels, which we can then use as named channels.

Comment: @DeathMetal With your current glob pattern, the `fromFilePairs` factory method should give you the sample names: `MM_tiny_n` and `MM_tiny_t`. I assumed your _FASTP_ and dowstream processes also return tuples containing the sample names/ids, but I might be wrong..

Comment: This is complicated for me, sorry. Would you mind explaining  in `tumor: sample_id.endsWith('_T')  return tuple( case_id, sample_id, bam )` what is **case_id**? Second, how does tuple has three elements in it?

Comment: If you get a chance, I've a new question at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/21310/nextflow-missing-value-declared-as-output-parameter-output-variable-defined

Comment: @DeathMetal The _case_id_ is really just the patient or case or donor from which the samples are derived. For example, `MM_tiny` would be the case or donor id here. Tuples can contain any number of elements. The elements don't even need to be of the same type necessarily.